# Slick Slider: slickSetOption() doesn't effect rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a slider:

```
<div class="super-slick responsive">
    <div class="profile-photo slider-image" style="height:400px;width:200px;background-color: blue;>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-photo slider-image" style="height:400px;width:200px;background-color: blue;>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-photo slider-image" style="height:400px;width:200px;background-color: blue;>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-photo slider-image" style="height:400px;width:200px;background-color: blue;>
    </div>
</div>
```

slider:

```
$(".super-slider").slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    rows: 1
})
```

...and everything works and updating settings works, but I cannot seem to update the number of rows using `slickSetOption`:

```
super_slider.slick("slickSetOption", "slidesPerRow", 2)
super_slider.slick("slickSetOption", "slidesToScroll", 1)
super_slider.slick("slickSetOption", "rows", 2, true)
```

but when I call `slickGetOption`, it tells me the change has taken place:

console:

```
> super_slider.slick("slickGetOption", "rows")
> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
super_slider.slick('destroy');
super_slider.slick({
        rows: 2
});
```

note that you have to specify all of your slick options along with rows